# Package.json specifies Node version but Azure tells me none is specified

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, azure-web-app-service

Im trying to write a custom deploy script for my Azure website. I'm getting some errors that I believe are related to Azure using an older version of Node.

All the places I found online say to specify the Node version in your `package.json` file like so:

```
"engines" : { "node" : "0.10.26" }
```

So I put that in my `package.json` file, but after pushing those changes, the log still shows the message:

```
The package.json file does not specify node.js engine version constraints.
The node.js application will run with the default node.js version 0.10.5.
```

What is going on here?

My `package.json` file:

`{
  "name": "app-kit",
  "namespace": "appkit",
  "APIMethod": "stub",
  "proxyURL": "http://localhost:8000",
  "proxyPath": "/api",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "test"
  },
  "engines" : {"node" : "0.10.26"},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "grunt server",
    "build": "grunt build:debug",
    "test": "grunt test:ci"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies" : {
    "express": "~3.4.8",
    "lockfile": "~0.4.2",
    "grunt": "~0.4.2",
    "grunt-cli": "~0.1.9",
    "load-grunt-config": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.7",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.6.2",
    "grunt-preprocess": "~3.0.1",
    "grunt-es6-module-transpiler": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-concat-sourcemap": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "~0.4.3",
    "grunt-usemin": "~0.1.13",
    "grunt-rev": "~0.1.0",
    "grunt-ember-templates": "~0.4.18",
    "originate": "~0.1.5",
    "grunt-es6-import-validate": "0.0.6",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "^0.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "express": "~3.4.8",
    "lockfile": "~0.4.2",
    "bower": "~1.2.7",
    "grunt": "~0.4.2",
    "grunt-cli": "~0.1.9",
    "load-grunt-config": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.7",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.6.2",
    "grunt-preprocess": "~3.0.1",
    "grunt-es6-module-transpiler": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-concat-sourcemap": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "~0.4.3",
    "grunt-usemin": "~0.1.13",
    "grunt-rev": "~0.1.0",
    "grunt-ember-templates": "~0.4.18",
    "grunt-contrib-testem": "~0.5.14",
    "express-namespace": "~0.1.1",
    "request": "~2.33.0",
    "loom-generators-ember-appkit": "~1.0.5",
    "originate": "~0.1.5",
    "loom": "~3.1.2",
    "connect-livereload": "~0.3.1",
    "grunt-es6-import-validate": "0.0.6",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "^0.11.0",
    "grunt-ftp-deploy": "^0.1.2"
  }
}`

I know there is duplication in devDependencies and dependencies which is not necessary. This was because I want to grunt build my app on azure, but some of the dependencies wouldn't install correctly b/c of C headers (or so it appeared). I tried to include only the ones necessary to build the prod version of the application in the dependencies key. If I can get this working on Azure I plan to clean this up.

Comment: I tried this and it worked for me, is your package.json file at the root of the repository (where the root of the site is)?

Comment: Yes. It seems like its not responding to the updates to `package.json`. I also removed a `postinstall` line from it but the log still shows "Failed at the app-kit@0.0.0 postinstall script." on the most recent try.

Comment: are you by any chance pushing a branch other than master?

Comment: No, only the master branch.

Comment: Could you include your `package.json` in your question?

Comment: I just edited the question to include it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to use iojs insetead of node and I've ran into the same/similar issue.

Please remove the start script line and follow the custom deploy scripts and all will be fine. You can find deployments scripts [here](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/iojs-azure) for running iojs. I think they can be adapted to run any node version.

I copied all files in my normal node project (with bin/www script) but they did not work. It seems that I need to make some changes to that script or remove it since otherwise, all things look to be working.

Good luck,